# getting error while passing data from child component to parent component

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular 7 application.
I am trying to send data from child component to parent component, for that I am using the @Output decorator with an EventEmitter.

```
 @Output() token:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

I'm getting the error:

> ERROR in src/app/header/header.component.ts(96,6): error TS2322:
>   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'EventEmitter'.

Here I am trying to send value:

```
token == eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySWQiOiI1MmYzZWEyMC0yMDQzLTQ5MjQtODg3Ny0yNTAzZTZkOTZmNTEiLCJleHAiOjE1ODE2NzQ4OTcsImlzcyI6Ik1hZ2ljTWluZCIsImF1ZCI6Ik1hZ2ljTWluZCJ9.DMcMPgM0B2hZRR-qSIQyIG9SDt_q_G9WON3ZtRXX78I
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you emit the value the parent will recive the token event

`this.token.emit(tokenValue);`

And, on parent you need to do something like:

```
<child (token)="handleToken($event)"></child>
```

Example of use: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter#usage-notes

Answer (score 0):

```
@Output() token: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>(); Initialize :

this.token.emit(tokenValue); // emit the value to the parent
```

And, in parent .HTML you need to capture the event:

```
<child (token)="tokenEvent($event)"></child>
```